# Epplus Issue - Removed Records: Formula from /xl/worksheets/sheet5.xml part

Tags: excel, epplus

Currently I am implementing EPPlus in my application and added the formula R1C1 Notation in coding for the correct result but after save everything when i opened the Excel sheet i am getting the following error:

Removed Records: Formula from /xl/worksheets/sheet5.xml part

I don't have any information

1. what is the error in formula because after open it show as blank nothing is there
2. No log for this so that we can sort this problem

Please let me know if anyone have any solution like how we can identify the cause of this issue so that i can correct it. I have used EPPlase and .Net Core 6 for implementation this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer of the above question:

Below scenario only work when there is a error in excel open and there is no formula showing and no value is showing in the cell. then use the below trick and can get the solution easily.

1. First enabled the R1C1 notation in excel. Please check the below link how we can enable it.
   https://trumpexcel.com/a1-r1c1-reference-notation-excel/
2. Debug your code copy the formula in the excel sheet where record should display and check what error is there. fix that error and do the same modification in your code and then check the excel file.

Error will be remove and it will work like a charm.